# Find Overlapping Matches

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Given a string (line from text file) I would like to find all substrings built like this:

> [[ words ]]

For example:

> [[foo [[ bar ]]

should return both

> [[foo [[ bar ]]

and

> [[ bar ]]

Another example:

> [[foo]] and [[bar]]

Should produce

> [[foo]]

and

> [[bar]]

I thought about a forumla like

```
\[\[.+\]\]
```

But it doesn't work correctly (it matches too much).

Thanks for help!

Comment: So that problem can't be solved with a regex?

Comment: I retract my previous statement - good answer @zx81.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overlapping Matches: Use Lookahead

For a lazy overlap, use this regex:

```
(?=(\[\[.?*\]\]))
```

In Python:

```
import re
pattern = r"(?=(\[\[.*?\]\]))"
print(re.findall(pattern, "[[foo [[ bar ]]"))
print(re.findall(pattern, "[[foo]] and [[bar]]"))
```

Output:

```
['[[foo [[ bar ]]', '[[ bar ]]']
['[[foo]]', '[[bar]]']
```

For a "greedy overlap", use `(?=(\[\[.*\]\]))`

Output:

```
['[[foo [[ bar ]]', '[[ bar ]]']
['[[foo]] and [[bar]]', '[[bar]]']
```

**Explanation**

- The lookahead `(?= ... )` asserts that what is inside the parentheses can be matched (but doesn't match it, so that we can find overlapping matches)
- The parentheses around `([[.*]]) capture the matched string to Group 1
- `\[\[` matches `[[`
- `.*` gredily matches any chars
- The star quantifier in `.*?` is made "lazy" by the `?` so that the dot only matches as many characters as needed to allow the next token to match (shortest match). Without the `?`, the `.*` first matches the whole string, then backtracks only as far as needed to allow the next token to match (longest match).
- `\]\]` matches `]]`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)
- [The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)
- [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: The 2nd test doesn't look right: "[[foo]] and [[bar]]" should return
['[[foo]]', '[[bar]]']

Comment: @MDo, you're right, you want a non-greedy match. See the example in my answer.

Comment: @MDo Did you change your requrements? I could have sworn I read you wanted `[[foo]] and [[bar]]', '[[bar]]`. To get the other one, just add a `?` to the `.*` : `.*?` Will add that to the solution.

Comment: Okay then, it's just morning blur! :) I split the answer into "greedy overlap" and "lazy overlap" so the two options are explained, explained `.*` vs `.*?` and added reference

Answer (score 1):

This uses a **Positive Lookahead** assertion for capturing, returning your overlapping matches:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(\[\[.*?\]\]))', '[[foo [[ bar ]]')
# ['[[foo [[ bar ]]', '[[ bar ]]']

>>> re.findall(r'(?=(\[\[.*?\]\]))', '[[foo]] and [[bar]]')
# ['[[foo]]', '[[bar]]']
```

**Note** the `?` following the `*` quantifier making your match non-greedy..