# Regular expression finditer: search twice on the same symbols

Tags: python, regex

I need to find matches in the text and get its positions. For example, I have to find "hello hello" in the text. When the text is "hello hello world hello hello", it's ok, I get the positions 0-11 and 18-29. But when the text is "hello hello hello world", I get only one position - 0-11. But I have to find the both ones (0-11 and 6-17). I mean, I get

1. **hello hello** hello world

but have to get

1. **hello hello** hello world
2. hello **hello hello** world

In another case I have to find the complex pattern: "hello 1,2 beautiful 2,4 world" - it means that between the words "hello" and "beautiful" could be one or two words and between the words "beautiful" and "world" 2, 3 or 4 words. And I have to find all the combinations.

This is the pattern: `re.compile(u'(^|[\[\]\/\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\} !<>:;,#@])(hello)(([\[\]\/\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\} !<>:;,#@%]+[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я$]+(-[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я$]+)*){1,2}[\[\]\/\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\} !<>:;,#@%]*)(beautiful)(([\[\]\/\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\} !<>:;,#@%]+[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я$]+(-[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я$]+)*){2,4}[\[\]\/\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\} !<>:;,#@%]*)(world)($|[\[\]\/\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\} !<>:;,#@])')`

And the text is "hello very beautiful beautiful very big world world". I can get the only one combination, but need to get 4:

1. **hello** very **beautiful** beautiful very big **world** world
2. **hello** very beautiful **beautiful** very big **world** world
3. **hello** very **beautiful** beautiful very big world **world**
4. **hello** very beautiful **beautiful** very big world **world**

How can I get all the combination of the matches when the matches intersect each other?

The flag re.DOTALL doesn't help.

```
import re

patterns = [
    u'(hello)(( [a-z]+ *){1,2})(beautiful)(( [a-z]+ *){2,4})(world)',
    u'hello hello'
]
text = u'hello hello hello world hello very beautiful beautiful very big world world'
for p in patterns:
    print p
    c = re.compile(p, flags=re.I+re.U)
    for m in c.finditer(text):
        print m.start(), m.end()
```

Result is

```
>>> (hello)(( [a-z]+ *){1,2})(beautiful)(( [a-z]+ *){2,4})(world)
>>> 24 69
(need 24 69 and 24 69 and 24 75 and 24 75 - because there are two positions of the word "beautiful")
>>> hello hello
>>> 0 11
(need 0 11 and 6 17)
```

The real examples of the patterns is:

> u"выйдите на улицы", u"избавить.* от", u"смотрите смотрите",
>   u"смеят.*"

And with the distance:

> имени 0,3 ленина
>
> целых 0,5 лет.*
>
> целых 0,5 лет.* 0,1 назад

**UPD**

The variant `u'(?=(hello hello))` helps with the patterns without distances between the words. But how can I use it in the pattern with distances, for example `(hello) (?:[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+ ){1,2}(beautiful) (?:[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+ ){2,4}(world)` ?

Comment: IMO if your regex looks like this, then you should probably go for another pattern or probably skip doing it via regex.

Comment: The problem not in the current regex. It coud be simpler, but the problem won't go away.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in your regex? Are you looking for repetitions of words?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have a list of patterns and have to find each occurrence of each pattern in the text. The patterns are different, and they could look like "xxx xxx" too.

Comment: We cannot help you find matches for your patterns unless you clearly describe what patterns you are looking for... I think you are trying to say that you are looking for repetitions of words with a single space in between.

Comment: If the pattern is not important give a **simple** and **small** example, such long and unclear question create a smoke screen around your real problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Overlapping Matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922121/find-overlapping-matches)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it helps with the simple patterns ("hello hello"), but unfortunately doesn't help with the patterns with the distances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still lacking a bit in clarity of what you wish to do, but I'll take a stab at it:

Regex to find repetitions without consumption:

```
([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)(?= (\1))
```

Regex to find `hello` `beautiful` and `world` with specific numbers of words in between:

```
(hello) (?:[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+ ){1,2}(beautiful) (?:[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+ ){2,4}(world)
```

### Final Update

What you wish to do is not easily done completely in regex in a single run.

Easier would be to loop and do different regexes:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(2,5):
        regStr='(hello) (?:\w+ ){' + str(i) + '}(beautiful) (?:\w+ ){' + str(j) +'}(world)'
```

and then do a second check for duplicates using

```
([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)(?= (\1))
```

Comment: Yes, it works on this example (as I wrote earlier, I have to find words with a predetermined number if words in between). But it doesn't solve my problem - it matches ones.

Comment: If I have the text "hello hello hello world hello very beautiful beautiful very big world world" and have to find "hello {1 or 2 words} beautiful {2, 3 or 4 words} world", I need get 4 matches:

1. hello hello hello world **hello** very **beautiful** beautiful very big **world** world
2. hello hello hello world **hello** very beautiful **beautiful** very big **world** world
3. hello hello hello world **hello** very **beautiful** beautiful very big world **world**
4. hello hello hello world **hello** very beautiful **beautiful** very big world **world**

Comment: added a final update, You are looking to do more than what is reasonable with regex when you already have a powerful programming tool (`python`)

Comment: I see. Thanks! In my project I do it by splitting the text by the tokens and trying to match tokens with suitable numbers with the regex. It works good and stable, but if it were possible to do something working like this using regular expression, maybe it would work faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try **below expression** than regexp, looks not that good but might solve your problem:

Expression:

```
 [pos for pos, char in enumerate(string) if string[pos:].find(pattern) == 0]
```

It gives list output with positions of the pattern in string.

```
In [43]: string = "hello very beautiful beautiful very big world world"
In [44]: pattern='hello'
In [45]: [pos for pos, char in enumerate(string) if string[pos:].find(pattern) == 0]
Out[45]: [0]
In [46]: pattern='very'
In [47]: [pos for pos, char in enumerate(string) if string[pos:].find(pattern) == 0]
Out[47]: [6, 31]
In [48]: pattern='world'
In [49]: [pos for pos, char in enumerate(string) if string[pos:].find(pattern) == 0]
Out[49]: [40, 46]
In [50]: pattern='very big'
In [51]: [pos for pos, char in enumerate(string) if string[pos:].find(pattern) == 0]
Out[51]: [31]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. The main reason why is I have to find the way how I can apply the pattern to the whole text once and get all the positions of the occurrences.